# Getting an error trying to run simulation in Windows 10

Tags: nativescript

Trying to get Genymtoion working, I am running the command:

```
tns run android --emulator --geny geny
```

and GenyMotion kicks off my vm named geny, but the App will not install or at least there is no icon.
Using Windows 10, see image below:

[image]

how do I get tns to install and run the developed App?

Comment: Hello born2net - please share some more info on how you run into this error - which command you are runnig on which platform and version and most importantly with what project ..the error is loggin the usage of experimental plugin.. have you installed this plugin manually or clned a project that uses it!?

Comment: sorry it was late last night, updated my issue with details... regards

Comment: Have you tried *tns run android --emulator --geny <genyId>*

Comment: well I am trying to get it to run in live-sync so dev will be as fast as possible, tried tns livesync android --watch --emulator and getting same error

Comment: I understand you are trying to do a liveSync, but first we want to see if it can run properly on your geny device.  Occasionally you need to deploy/run it first on the device before livesync will actually work.  So can you try the *tns run android --emulator --geny <genyId>* command and verify it works properly.  Please note you do NEED the --geny and <yourGenyId> for it to actually for it to launch on geny, if you don't include them, it might launch a normal emulator rather than the geny emulator.

Comment: the good news is that if I run run android --emulator --geny geny (that's what I named the vm: geny) all "seems" to run well in the script, and GenyMotion launches a new VM but the App never starts :(

Comment: let me add that when I see "installing C:\msweb\nativescript-todo\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\samplengtodomvc-debug.apk through adb" the Settings dialog opens for a second in Geny, and script continues with "running C:\msweb\nativescript-todo\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\samplengtodomvc-debug.apk through adb" and that's all I get, nothing opens up :( so basically the App is not getting installed... and I did enbale dev mode for the device...

Comment: I edited the post with a new image, and the command I run is: > tns run android --emulator --geny geny

Comment: Wow, that is really weird.  If you go into the menu on the android, is the app present?

Comment: Ok, if the app isn't present I would guess that the issue is actually a conflict between adb versions.   Geny motion comes with its own version of ADB, tns has its own and of course your actual Android sdk has its own.   By default geny when starting up will use its own version of adb.  But tns will use the Android version then fallback to using its own if the android version isn't found.    Quit out of the geny emulator, goto a dos prompt and type *adb kill-server* then click on the settings in Geny's control panel, and click on "ADB" and tell it to use the Android version of ADB.  Try again.

Comment: tx for the support, I switched the settings to Android SDK but still it does not launch the App :(

Comment: Can you try to go to the /platforms/android/build/apk and drag and drop the apk onto the emulator and see if it installs?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1.) Dtart your Genymotion and run the desired emulator (it state should look like the one iin the screenshoot)

2.) In your prompt/shell run the follownig command

```
tns device
```

It should return a log with your connected devices.
If you have only one emulator started it should look like this

```
┌───┬─────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ # │ Device Name │ Platform │ Device Identifier   │ Type     │ Status    │
│ 1 │ vbox86p     │ Android  │ 192.168.56.101:5555 │ Emulator │ Connected │
└───┴─────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

3.) Again from your shell run the following :

```
tns run android
```

or

```
tns livesync --watch android
```

No need to explicitly specify the emulator ID if you don't have more then one running.
Even if you have more then one emulator runnig the above command will start your app on all of them (which is also very useful for testing but its good to have a monster hardware in taht case..)

I have also noticed that on the screenshot your emulator is on the default favovites page - try tapping on the middle **apps icon** (the circle with a lot of dots) and search for your app in the list of all apps there.

Comment: regardless of what I do, GenyMotion will not install my apk :/